# Persistence of a variable through post backs but specific to the user of the page

Tags: vb.net, persistence, shared, public

I am working on a website with .aspx pages and code behind in VB.Net. On a page I need a Public Shared variable like

```
Public Shared comments As String() = New String(2) {"", "", ""}
```

since I need the persistence of the value of "comments" through post backs of the page. At least I think having it Public Shared is the only way to keep the persistence, unless you guys tell me that I am wrong.

But on the other hand I don't want other users who might be using the same page conflict their  "comments" data with other users. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the level of persistence you need.

If you only need the comments to live on the page until the user has navigated away from it, use your page's ViewState:

```
Public Property Comments As String()
    Get
        If Me.ViewState("Comments") Is Nothing Then
            Me.ViewState("Comments") = New String(2) {"", "", ""}
        End If
        Return Me.ViewState("Comments")
    End Get
    Set(value As String())
        Me.ViewState("Comments") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

If you'd like the values to persist for the page between navigating away and newly landing on the page again (i.e. initial load rather than postback), use your Session state bag:

```
Public Property Comments As String()
    Get
        If Me.Session("MyPage_Comments") Is Nothing Then
            Me.Session("MyPage_Comments") = New String(2) {"", "", ""}
        End If
        Return Me.Session("MyPage_Comments")
    End Get
    Set(value As String())
        Me.Session("MyPage_Comments") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

If you'd like this to persist even after the session is expired and the user returns later, you'd need to write to a backing store that would link the user to their comments such as a database, or--and I say this with much less enthusiasm--write out to something like an XML file, and then load the value on your initial page load in a statement such as:

```
 Public Sub PageLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     If Not Me.IsPostBack
         ' Read the value from the backing store
     End If
 End Sub
```

When using a backing store, however, I generally recommend using one of the data source controls along with a databound control such as a ListView or GridView to display the information.